# How to get a callback from event listener in Nuxt/Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm on Nuxt 2.15.8 and I want to get the result of my emitted event.
I have a child component where the event is emitted . then receive it on parent component and do some api calls . I want a two way communication so that I can tell the child the event was emitted, api call was sent and the result has been received , so do some action ! (currently doing so by passing a boolean prop to child and watch on that)

what I do right now:

my parent component :

```js
<template>
    <childcomponent :result="result" @childEvent="handleEvent" /> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
    components:{ childcomponent },
    data(){
        return{
            result: false
        }
    }
    methods:{
        async handleEvent(val){
            let res = this.$axios.get(`/example/${val}`)
            if(res){
                this.result = true
            }else{
                this.result = false
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

my child component :

```js
<template>
    <div @click="doSomething"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props:['result'],
    watch:{
        result(e){
            if(e){
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
    methods:{
        doSomething(){
            // do something
            this.$emit('childEvent', 'val')
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I know I can use `$nuxt.$emit()` to emit another event from parent and receive it on child , but I want something simple like

```js
//child
this.$emit('childEvent', 'val' , (result)=>{
    // result of event handler sent from parent
})

// Or

let res = await this.$emit('childEvent', 'val')
if(res){
    // do something
}
```

Is it possible at all??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you may want to notify the child. If you just want a "loading" state, a prop would do (set loading to true when axios starts and then to false when it finishes). By the way, the axios api is asyncronous (promise based), so you have to use await:

```
let res = await this.$axios.get(`/example/${val}`)
```

But going to the topic, you can call methods of the child component directly, just use ref to access the instance:

```
<template>
    <childcomponent ref="child" :result="result" @childEvent="handleEvent" /> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
    components:{ childcomponent },
    data(){
        return{
            result: false
        }
    }
    methods:{
        async handleEvent(val){
            let res = await this.$axios.get(`/example/${val}`)
            this.$refs.child.getResult(res)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And the child:

```
<template>
    <div @click="doSomething"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods:{
        doSomething(){
            // do something
            this.$emit('childEvent', 'val')
        },
        getResult(res) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I already know some ways do so, but it's all about reusable component . the function must be on parent and child must just emit and get the result . If I add `this.$refs.child.getResult(res)` , I must do it on every parent which is not preferable , at least here . FYI this is my issue, when I click on child , I fetch a list in parent and pass it to child but for some reason the list won't be shown , so I'm gonna refresh that part in child component by changing `key` . I want it to happen internally in child , free of parent's codes.

Comment: Ok I see. But why not using a prop to pass the list back to the child? So the child renders the list in its current state getting the update after the fetch. Or alternatively, why not letting the child to fetch and keep the data internally? In my opinion they are better patterns that handling update events manually.

Comment: for your second question , re-usability ! and for your first easier re-usability :D ! to pass a prop, in every parent, I must define that, fill it after fetch and pass it to child so that the child can refresh itself !! in my opinion it can become cumbersome

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem well. The list/data should normally be just in one place, and the holder of the data should be the only one modifying it. If you want that list to be used in many parts across your app, maybe vuex is what you are looking for.

Comment: For the context of parent/child, yes, use `this.$emit` and `props`... that's what it's for. However what @MojtabaBarari touched on is actually a "2-way event bus", which can work in any context (globally, which inherently means between parent/child too). This is something you build yourself using a plain JS global object. The big question is does Nuxt provide this in any way at all, so you don't have to build your own event bus.

Comment: @MarsAndBack Nuxt.js has an internal event bus. with `$nuxt.$emit` and `this.$nuxt.$on` you can send and receive events on any levels. even from child of parent A to child of parent B

Comment: Yes, I use Nuxt's event bus all the time... but it's a _one-way_ event bus; there is no callback. If there were, we might have something like `this.$nuxt.$emit("myEvent", myPayload, myFuncToRunIfWeGetAReturn() )`. Example: I broadcast an event throughout my Vue app saying "Hey, this thing happened!" and in some component somewhere I want to send a response along the lines of "Ok, received the event. This is what I think about it...". This has absolutely nothing to do with Vue component parent/child props/emits.